# Accessing ECS container from AWS Lambda running in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda function in a public VPC (no NAT Gateway), which is supposed to call another ECS service, which is publicly accessible via a Load Balancer. As the lambda function does not have internet access, it can not access the ECS service. Can I somehow use internal networking (specifically the existing load balancer) so that I do not need to setup a NAT Gateway? Everything is deployed to the same public subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is deployed to the public subnet (or even in different one's but in the same vpc), you can simply create a new "Internal" load balancer. There are 2 kinds of load balancers:

1. Public
2. Internal

This internal load balancer will then be available to be used by your lambda function (over a private ip, resolved through a DNS provided by the LB).  (The assumption is that your current load balancer is a public one, who's DNS resolves to public IPs.)
I am not aware of any way that a public load balancer be accessed by a private IP.

However, at this point, I would ask a seemingly unrelated question, but probably important design question:
What forces you to put your lambda function within a public subnet in a VPC? A lambda function will never have a Public IP, which means it can never access the internet without a NAT gateway, regardless of where it is placed.
An interesting follow up question would be, what prevents you to put your lambda function outside the VPC, where it would have open access to the internets? :)

Comment: The lambda needs access to RDS which is deployed to the VPC. I have now deployed a NAT gateway and moved the lambda function to the private subnet so that I can access third-party services. All subnets are also associated with VPC Endpoints. Are those still used even tough the lambda has internet access, so does AWS route traffice preferably through the endpoints instead of NAT gateway?

Comment: That should do the trick.
As for your question, if you still have the service endpoint in your route table for your private subnet, then your request will be routed via the most specific route entry in your route table. 
In simple words, YES, if you still have the entry in the route table that points to the service endpoint.

Check the following from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html#RouteTables:

"Route priority
We use the most specific route in your route table that matches the traffic to determine how to route the traffic (longest prefix match)."